# Parsing SQL CREATE TABLE statement using ANTLR4

Tags: mysql, parsing, antlr4

**Lexer file** code is as follows:

```
lexer grammar CreateLexer;

CREATE
   : 'create' | 'CREATE'
   ;

NUMBER_OF_SHARDS:'number_of_shards' | 'NUMBER_OF_SHARDS';


NUMBER_OF_REPLICAS:'number_of_replicas' | 'NUMBER_OF_REPLICAS';


ID
  : ( 'a' .. 'z' | 'A' .. 'Z' | '_' | '\u4e00' .. '\u9fa5' | '-')+
  ;


INT
  : [0-9]+
  ;


NEWLINE
  : '\r'? '\n' -> skip
  ;


WS
  : [\t\r\n]+ -> skip
  ;


INDEX
  : 'index' | 'INDEX'
  ;

TABLE:'table';
```

and **parser file** code is also as follows:

```
parser grammar CreateParser;

options
   { tokenVocab = CreateLexer; }
stat
   : create_clause
   ;

create_clause
   : CREATE INDEX index_name shards? replicas?
   ;

index_name
   : (ID)*(INT)*
   ;

shards
   : NUMBER_OF_SHARDS INT
   ;

replicas
   : NUMBER_OF_REPLICAS INT
   ;
```

and this is my **testing code** demonstrates how I use modules above:

```
String sql = "create index A number_of_shards 1 number_of_replicas 1";
CreateLexer createLexer = new CreateLexer(new ANTLRInputStream(sql));
createLexer.removeErrorListeners();

CreateParser parser = new CreateParser(new CommonTokenStream(createLexer));
ParseTree tree = parser.stat();
System.out.println(tree.toStringTree(parser));
```

when I run the test code above, I got an error:

```
line 1:7 missing INDEX at 'index'
(stat (create_clause create <missing INDEX> (index_name index A) (shards number_of_shards 1) (replicas number_of_replicas 1)))
```

After I replaced 'INDEX' with 'TABLE' at 'create_clause' in paser file, and replaced 'index' with 'table' in the test code as:

**test code:**

```
String sql = "create table A number_of_shards 1 number_of_replicas 1";
```

**paser file:**

```
create_clause
   : CREATE TABLE index_name shards? replicas?
   ;
```

and I run it again, it still got the same error:

```
line 1:7 missing 'table' at 'table'
(stat (create_clause create <missing 'table'> (index_name table A) (shards number_of_shards 1) (replicas number_of_replicas 1)))
```

However, after I deleted the key word **TABLE** in parser file as follows:

```
create_clause
   : CREATE index_name shards? replicas?
   ;
```

weird thing happens, I got no error:

```
(stat (create_clause create (index_name table A) (shards number_of_shards 1) (replicas number_of_replicas 1)))
```

Can anyone tell me why SQL Statement like 'CREATE TABLE' can not be parsed? Do I miss anything? Thanks in advance!

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Antlr generally matches lexer rules based first on text match length, then on order in the grammar. So, your `INDEX` and `TABLE` rules will never be matched. Instead, the text is rendered in `ID` tokens.

By removing the requirement for an explicit `INDEX` token, you removed the cause of the error.

As a general rule, always dump the token stream so that you can see what the lexer is actually doing.

Comment: THANK YOU!!  This really solved my problem!! As you said, I know what my issue was